# Bash Script - case esac - fails

Tags: shell-script, scripting, case

Is the following script right??? It was doing OK until yesterday!

I've written the following script to help a cron job running every minute and calling some other script which may cause a command to be executed more than once, the expected behaviour is to have 4 process of the job, anything less or more should be causing a restart, so please let me know if the following script is right or not?

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$(pidof command | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting command:     $(date)" >> log

    /usr/bin/sh x.sh
    ;;

4)  # all ok

    echo "All OK" >> log
    ;;

*)  for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "x" | grep "y" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done

    echo "Removed PIDs and RESTARTING FFMPEG: $(date)" >> /root/afarinEidSTs/log

    /usr/bin/sh x.sh
    ;;

esac
```

It will not kill proccesses even if they get more than 4, why?

In log file, I will just see the result of `"Restarting command:     $(date)"`.

It is so weird, because pidof `ffmpeg | wc -w` will display 23, but the script is not killing all and restarting them again!

---

I have also tried using `([0-3])` instead of `0)` as @jordanm said, but didn't help.

Comment: Uh, so you intend to kill *all* processes on your system which contain both the letters "x" and "y"? This will never allow it get up to 4, so it will only work if you have exactly 4 the first time you run it. The first condition should probably be `[0-3]`.

Comment: @jordanm Did what you said, but it got more again! BTW, won't `[0-3]` be the same as `*)` including `1-2-3` since not mentioned in first conditions?

Comment: If you're literally running `pidof command`, when the command you're actually running is `/usr/bin/sh x.sh`.... won't the number of PIDs be always 0?

Comment: No, `x.sh` is calling `command` inside itself, so `pidof command` will show the number of `command` not `x.sh`.

Comment: Is the `command` a script or a linux built in or a `c/java` binary?

Comment: linux built in which will be called by `x.sh` script in four different ways, and that's why I need exact 4 numbers of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your cron or something that you are using for doing your jobs, cannot execute all commands you have used. To fix the issue, I recommend you use the the bsolute path of any command - taken by using `which pidof`, `which grep` &c :

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$(/usr/sbin/pidof command | /usr/sbin/wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting command:     $(date)" >> log

    /usr/bin/sh x.sh
    ;;

4)  # all ok

    echo "All OK" >> log
    ;;

*)  for pid in $(/usr/sbin/ps -ef | /usr/sbin/grep "x" | /usr/sbin/grep "y" | /usr/sbin/awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done

    echo "Removed PIDs and RESTARTING FFMPEG: $(date)" >> /root/afarinEidSTs/log

    /usr/bin/sh x.sh
    ;;

esac
```

Double check full paths in your system.